# Output table contents with limit and filter

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I'm finding the boto dynamoDB documentation [lacking almost completely of examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#QueryAndScan.Scan).

In Python, I simply want to output the contents of a table with a limit of a number of records, say 500 of the latest ones, from a certain date.

Here is what I have...

```
import boto.dynamodb
import sys

#----------PUBLIC VARIABLES--------------------------#

connection = boto.dynamodb.connect_to_region(
    'us-east-1',
    aws_access_key_id='somekey',
    aws_secret_access_key='somesecretkey')

#----------------------------------------------------#

def info():
    print('#########################_TABLE_NAMES_#########################')
    #get and print list of tables
    tablenames = connection.list_tables()
    for table in tablenames:
        print('DynamoDB table: %s' % table)
        #print(connection.describe_table(table))
    print('###############################################################' + '\n')

def main():
    print('###########################_RESULTS_###########################')   
    scan = myTable.scan(scan_filter=None, attributes_to_get=['SomeField'])
    results = []
    for x in scan:
        results.append(x['SomeField'])
    print('###############################################################' + '\n')  
def writeError(error):
    try:
        f = open("error.txt", "w")
        try:
            f.write(error) # Write a string to a file
        finally:
            f.close()
    except IOError:
        print "WriteError - Error!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        info()
        main()
    except:
        writeError("Unexpected error:" + str(sys.exc_info()))
        print "Error"
```

The table I have hasn't got any custom indexes so I'd be looking for something pretty basic as an example.

I'm sorry I don't have a better attempt, but I've researched and not found a lot to go on.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your script to print out the first 500 scan results for each table. Don't forget to correct the field name (I put someField):

```
import boto.dynamodb2
from boto.dynamodb2.table import Table
import sys

#----------PUBLIC VARIABLES--------------------------#

connection = boto.dynamodb2.connect_to_region(
    'us-east-1')

#----------------------------------------------------#

def getTableNames():
    '''get list of tables'''
    tablenames = connection.list_tables()["TableNames"]
    return tablenames

def main(tablenames=[]):
    print('###########################_RESULTS_###########################')  
    for table in tablenames:
        print "Table Name: " + table
        myTable = Table(table)
        scan = myTable.scan()
        results = []
        for item in scan:
            if len(results) >= 500:
                break
            results.append(item.get('someField'))
        for result in results:
            print result
    print('###############################################################' + '\n')  
def writeError(error):
    try:
        f = open("error.txt", "w")
        try:
            f.write(error) # Write a string to a file
        finally:
            f.close()
    except IOError:
        print "WriteError - Error!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        tablenames = getTableNames()
        main(tablenames)
    except:
        writeError("Unexpected error:" + str(sys.exc_info()))
        print "Error"
```

Please note that DynamoDB doesn't provide scan results in any order. If you want them ordered by the latest changes, you can use a solution based on DynamoDB Streams https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html or add a secondary index: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html

Comment: I get the error `Unexpected error:(<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>, TypeError('list indices must be integers, not str',)`

Comment: Also will this give me 500 records from each table? Or can I define a specific table (preferred)?

Comment: Can you please provide the DynamoDB table DescribeTable output? This will provide the key schema and attribute definitions. Happy to help you get started with the DynamoDB boto/python SDK.

This question seems to be generic - can you provide more information on exactly the use case you are trying to achieve and I will attempt to provide you with a better script / more information on how to implement the application on DynamoDB

Comment: Let's say I want to return all records for columns 'blue', 'green' and 'yellow', with a limit of 500 of the latest records. I don't have secondary indexes so I know this might be tricky. Perhaps we could use a date range instead. The requirement is that I'm running some automated tests, where I just need to return the last bunch of records to check for some data. I can handle the checks, but can't for the life of me figure out how to simply query the table. I'm only familiar with MySQL which is relational.

Comment: Without a range key on the attribute you want to query (base table or secondary index schema), you cannot efficiently query in DynamoDB - you'd have to scan the entire contents of the table and perform the analysis in the client application.

DynamoDB doesn't support query limits - when you issue a query it will return up to the limit parameter you specify in each page, rather than in the total. It's up to the client application to stop paging through the results when it receives enough records. Additionally, you'll have to include a timestamp as an attribute.

Comment: Ok so how would I query the entire table? This should be OK as it's just a test table with minimal data. Also is it possible to delete the table after the query? (thanks for the help by the way).

Comment: Yes. The Scan API is what you are looking for. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html

To delete the table, issue a DeleteTable request:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteTable.html